# assert not working on android 5.1.1?

Tags: android, assert, android-5.1.1-lollipop

My code uses `assert` calls extensively.

After updating to 5.1.1 (tested on Nexus 4 & Nexus 5), the assertion calls are being ignored. Selecting "debug app" under Developer options made no difference.

Had anyone solve this issue? (Before I'm forced to replace all the assertions with some `myAssert(..)`).

**Update:**
The issue I've opened was closed with this comment:

> debug.assert was never implemented.

It appears there is not much demand for this tool, beats me.

`assert` *was* an extremely powerful tool.

Some advantages:

1. Enabled and disabled in runtime using:

   adb shell setprop debug.assert 1 (or 0)
2. comparing to some `public static myAssert(boolean condition,String message)` - myAssert executes/evaluates the `message` in any case, while `assert` does so only if the `condition` is false. So `myAssert(..)` is expensive in cpu and memory, especially if you need meaningful messages such as `Arrays.toString(..)`. And you'll need to skip any `myAssert` call if you're doing profiling.

Comment: I've opened a case for it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175697

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google says `assert` was never officially supported, and now it is not even there.
RIP.